# How to add subgroup to a group in contacts in iPhone apps programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I am new to this contacts applications in iPhone applications. my requirement is to add groups and sub groups to the groups Programmatically. I have achieved how to add groups to the iPhone default contact database. now I want add sub-groups to the existing groups.

I have tried to add sub-group to the groups by using ABgroup method ABGroupCreateInSource()
my code is like this

```
ABRecordRef subGroup = ABGroupCreateInSource(group);
ABRecordSetValue(subGroup, kABGroupNameProperty, groupName, &error);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(contacts, subGroup, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(contacts, &error);
```

but application is crashing by giving exception like "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x158190'"

some body please help me. some help will be really helpful to my application.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This post may be helpful.

[Obtaining Specific ABSource from ABAddressBook in iOS 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679641/obtaining-specific-absource-from-abaddressbook-in-ios-4/4679664#4679664)

Answer (score 0):

```
ABRecordRef subGroup = ABGroupCreateInSource(group);
```

is definately wrong.Since the souce is not indicate the super group.The soure should be ABSource type,not the ABGroup.

As I know there are no concept of subgroup.Sorry about that : (

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ABGroup](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABGroupRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) reference, "Groups may not contain other groups."